# How to access a div's id with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to figure out how to compare a div's id to a value. For example, if I get all of the divs using

```
divs = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
```

and then, how would I check to see if the first div's id is equal to "foo"

```
if divs[0].id == "foo":
```

Like that? ^^^ How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

`BeautifulSoup()` would return you the "soup" object. You need to find the `div` element using `find()` or `find_all()` or `select()` or other method. Example using `find()`:

```
div = soup.find("div")
```

`div` would be a [`Tag` object](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) in this case. There is a [*dictionary-like access* to tag attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
if div.get("id") == "foo":
```